# Invoking parameterised function of javascript from managed bean in jsf

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, javabeans

I have googled it several times but i can't get a solution. I want to make javascript function call from the bean class in jsf and i get that using the following code.
`RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("handleResize()");`

and is workign fine. But I want to give two parameters to that function height and width. How can it be done ? please help

Comment: Maybe `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("handleResize(100, 200)");`?

Comment: Not static values. I tried with static values and it work. But i want to pass dynamic values.

Comment: @nik Give us an example.

Comment: @RongNK like int h=500,w=300; RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("handleResize(h, w)");

Comment: @nik `String str = "handleResize(" + h + "," + w + ")"`, and then `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute(str)`

Answer (score 5):

You seem to fail to grasp the fact that in the context of Java/JSF, all the HTML, CSS and JavaScript code are merely plain vanilla `String`s and you seem to expect that HTML/CSS/JS somehow magically runs inside Java/JSF code. This is not true. Java/JSF is a HTML/CSS/JS code producer, not executor. The webbrowser retrieves them all as one big `String` and then parses and executes it.

If you want to invoke a JS function with parameters supplied, like so when you would do in real JS code:

```
handleResize(500, 300);
```

And you have those values as Java variables, then you just need to make sure that you write Java code in such way that exactly the above `String` is produced (again, this is just Java code, no JS code):

```
String call = "handleResize(" + w + ", " + h + ")";
```

You can verify beforehand by printing it to the stdout/logger:

```
System.out.println(call);
```

It must print exactly the desired valid JS function call syntax `handleResize(500, 300);`.

If it does, then just pass that unmodified to `RequestContext#execute()`.

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute(call);
```